# AJAX GET request content not responding to jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax, get

I'm currently trying to display the memberlist of all my users with a AJAX get request. Everything is working fine, but the content it appends to my HTML does not respond to another jQuery script.

Is there a way to hardcode the retrieved content in my HTML?

Here's get request I'm using:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    $.get("../assets/includes/memberlist.php", function(data) {
        $(".to-show").html(data);
    });
});
```

The retrieved content has several divs in it, which I should be able to toggle. But this isn't working. If I view my source code, the appended data isn't visible in the source code.

Here's the script which should do the toggle trick:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {

  var $mores = $('.event-toggle').hide();
  var $items = $('.event-title');

  var $titles = $('.event-title').click(function() {
    var $more = $(this).next('.event-toggle').slideToggle();
    $mores.not($more).slideUp();
    var $title = $(this).toggleClass('event-title active-title');
    $titles.not($title).removeClass('active-title').addClass('event-title')
    return false;
  });
});
```

Thanks for any help!

Comment: `but the content it appends to my HTML does not respond to another jQuery script` So why not posting the other relevant jQuery script? Sounds like you need to delegate event ***or*** initialize plugin once content added...  http://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/

Comment: So to delegate click event: `$(".to-show").on('click', '.event-title', function(){...});`  but beware about `var $titles` then

Comment: Added the script. Alright, I'll take a look into that. thanks :)

Comment: Make sure you're actually using the correct relative file path. This should be the first you want to check when no data shows up.

Comment: The data does show up, but it doesn't get hard coded into my html file...

Comment: Do you mean you are not able to see the expected changes in you html page. Is the new HTML is appended to the place you want it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You won't be able to see any newly added snippets to the DOM by just viewing the source code of the page. You should be able to use Firebug or Chrome developer tools and then inspect the DOM to see the newly added content.

Also bear in mind that the JQuery GET request is asynchronous so you cannot rely on it being available in your second snippet. You should ideally have placed that code in a function and then called it when the GET request completed successfully.

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    $.get("../assets/includes/memberlist.php", function(data) {
        $(".to-show").html(data);
        /* FUNCTION TO OPERATE ON NEWLY ADDED DOM SHOULD GO HERE */
    });
});
```

Comment: Thanks, that works for me. Should have thought of that myself though. :)